# replace or remove a character from a string in javascript didn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, replace

If I select a word and it contain " 's ", I want it to be removed or replaced with space. For example if I have the sentence: "king's bed" and I selected "king's" I want it to be in the variable only "king".

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
  var word2 = selectedWord.split(' ');
  var word= word2.replace(/'s/g, "");
```

it gave me this error:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Object [object Array] has no method 'replace'
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'replace'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of your functions:

```
var word = selectedWord.replace(/'s/g, '').split(' ');
```

`.split()` returns an array, which doesn't have a `replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, `word2` is an **array**, not a string.
Arrays do not have a `replace` method.

You probably shouldn't be calling `split()`.

Comment: So you beat me, and you did it better!!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the split method returns an array.

Comment: thank you  i didn't know that before cz i'm new in this. thank you:)